# Get registered entities in ModelBuilder with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, soft-delete

I can't find this asked anywhere. Basically, I'd like to know whether or not it's possible to get all registered entities in a DbModelBuilder.

If you need context, basically I'm implementing Soft Deletes in my application.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries();
    var deleted = changeSet.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    foreach (var deletedItem in deleted.Where(x => x.Entity is SoftDeleteable))
    {
        SoftDelete(deletedItem);
    }
}
```

Without getting too into the details, the above algorithm is handling what I want to do, and is working. If I have a model class that implements the "SoftDeleteable" interface (which is just one "Deleted" property), EF won't delete it, but instead set the "Deleted" column.

The real problem comes about when I have to do this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>()
    .Map(p => p.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
    .Ignore(p => p.Deleted);
```

for every thing that implements SoftDeletable manually. I'd much rather do something like

```
foreach(var entity in modelBuilder.RegisteredEntities.Where(x => x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SoftDeleteable))) {
    entity.Map(p => p.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
        .Ignore(p => p.Deleted);
}
```

But I can't find anything like that "RegisteredEntities" property. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to `Ignore` the property? Doesn't that make your soft-delete not work?

Comment: I didn't add that because that's not really relevant to the question, but it's all handled via executing sql. I don't want the user of a SoftDeletable object to have to worry about the Deleted flag at all. They're just using the object like normal, and deleting it like normal (removing it from the dbContext).

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply do updates instead of actual deletes?  We do something very similar, we have a repository and the delete method doesn't actually call delete instead it updates the status column for the record.  It seems like you're over complicating something that could/should be very simple

Comment: Because this isn't a green field project, and there's plenty of places where deletes are happening outside of a repository. It's much nicer to handle it as SaveChanges, in our use case.

Comment: Also, what do you do when you query for the objects? Do you always include the "Where Deleted = false" in all your navigation properties? With the solution I'm implementing, you don't have to worry about that

Comment: I would use the repository pattern and stop exposing the EF Context directly to your UI.  This would save you from having to try and override EF functionality and it would result in better code.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. For example, we have Users in our code. Users are part of a Company. We can definitely have the user repository filter out the deleted users (which we do now), but what happens when you get a reference to a Company, and then do "company.Users"? You will always have to remember to include Where(x => !x.Deleted) whenever you do it. I'm encapsulating that logic.